# TightVNC on Ubuntu does not see clipboard contents from MAC OS VNC Viewer

Tags: macos, ubuntu, clipboard, tightvnc

I installed [TightVNC](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04) on Ubuntu

On mac I use ScreenSharing tool or [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) Viewer (Java version)

I can copy-paste from Ubuntu to MAC, but not from Mac to Ubuntu.

Did you manage to work with **TightVNC** from MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered, VNC is very bad with clipboard operations.
So I switched to another technology - x2go (it has server and client and easily works with clipboard).